# cloud9-ide importing database in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, import, cloud9-ide

How can I actually get the key in the "path" portion of command: source PATH_TO_SQL_FILE.sql?

The Sql (i.e database folder>database.sql) file is inside my cloud 9 ide workspace.

I have tried the steps below:

1. Login to mysql (i.e mysql-ctl cli)
2. Use the database
3. source /database/database.sql

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you're trying to do? Are you referring to any of the Cloud9 documentation, like https://docs.c9.io/setting_up_mysql.html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can upload your sql dump to the cloud9 instance.

Create a new folder under workspace.  Upload your sql dump to the folder.  Right click the folder and click "Open terminal here", from bash run `pwd` to get the path to the folder.

In MySql ctl, enter the path to your sql dump here.

My path:

```
source> /home/ubuntu/workspace/SQL/sqldump.sql
```